# Uploadify loads twice (one never finishes - causes error in IE 10)

Tags: uploadify, internet-explorer-10

I'm using the flash version of Uploadify in a project. When using Firebug I can see that uploadify.swf is loading twice. One row completes as normal while the other row (top one in the image) never finishes.

When running the website in IE 10 and change page I get error "Object expected" because of the second swf-loading (that never finishes).

Two main questions:
1. Why is uploadify loading twice?
2. Can I solve the problem with IE 10 somehow? 
   I've noticed that setting  makes it work, but I don't want to do this since a lot of other stuff is affected.

The code (nothing special):

```
$('#upload').uploadify({
    uploader: ...,
    swf: '../Content/uploadify.swf'
});
```

[image]